# Processing timestamped (or changing) filenames in ODI package

Tags: oracle, etl

I am working on `Oracle Data Integrator 11g`

I have to create an ODI package, where I need to process an incoming file. The file name is not a constant string, as it has a timestamp entry appended to it, something like this: `FILTER_DATA_011413.TXT`

Due to the **MMDDYY**, I can't hardcode the filename in my package. The way, we're handling it right now is, a shell script lists the files in the directory, and loads the filename into a table (using control file). This table is then queried to get the filename and the same is passed to the variable which stores the filename for processing.

I am looking for any other way, where I can avoiud having this temporary table to store the file name.

Can someone suggest me any alternative?

Comment: I think it is `mmddyy` :)

Comment: @Incognito did you fix this problem please I have same problem and I am using ODI 12c please can you help me